# A pet rabbit called Belle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, language, music

> I have a pet rabbit. Her name is Belle. Most people think she is French (because Belle means "beautiful" in French, and my, this rabbit is beautiful) but she is not. Her fur was also painted **R**ainbow by someone sharing the surname of a French philosopher, but she is not French!
>
> - When she sings, she is black and white.
> - Although she is a little rabbit, her ears are longer than any other rabbit with the size of her head, where the ratio of the length of her head to the length of one ear is 4:23
> - Her face is fully symmetrical, being about two hands wide.
> - *You* can always watch her through a window at H1Dvg2MxQn8.
> - She sang in a piece very famous, being my own, actually (though played by the same guy that painted her) also making me pretty famous. (And no, I myself am not French either!)
> - Her nationality is not the same as mine, but is instead given by her name just as well as the name of my song.
> - Each point represents a second except this very one.

Along with other minor questions...

***Where can you find Belle?*** 
***What is her nationality?***

Bonus: 
 ***What is my name?***

---

<sup>This puzzle was created with the intention of no disrespect towards the French.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Belle can be found [here](https://youtu.be/H1Dvg2MxQn8?t=263). She is Italian.

Her fur was also painted Rainbow by someone sharing the surname of a French philosopher, but she is not French!

> Jean-Jacques **Rousseau** is a French philosopher. In the video, she is rainbow-colored.

When she sings, she is black and white.

> The piano has black and white keys.

Although she is a little rabbit, her ears are longer than any other rabbit with the size of her head, where the ratio of the length of her head to the length of one ear is 4:23.

> At 4:23 in the link mentioned below, it looks like a bunny with ears.

Her face is fully symmetrical, being about two hands wide.

> The 'face' of the bunny as shown is the length of the two hands of Rousseau.

You can always watch her through a window at H1Dvg2MxQn8.

> H1Dvg2MxQn8 leads to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1Dvg2MxQn8).

She sang in a piece very famous, being my own, actually (though played by the same guy that painted her) also making me pretty famous. (And no, I myself am not French either!)

> [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1Dvg2MxQn8) is the famous piece by 'Rousseau'. Googling 'La Campanella' yields the first result as Rousseau's video, which perhaps made you much more popular and well-known than before.

Her nationality is not the same as mine, but is instead given by her name just as well as the name of my song.

> La Campanella is Italian and means "The little bell".

Each point represents a second except this very one.

> I have no idea about this one. Perhaps the fact that Belle lasts on the screen for 6-7 seconds (which is the same as the number of points?)

About your name,

> I think you are Franz Liszt (who is Hungarian).

Comment: Yup! All of this is correct — each and every one. Good job! You will be getting the tick in $24$ hours from now :D

Comment: Yay! My first answer! Thanks! :D

Comment: Your first answer to be $\color{green}{\text{accepted}}$, that is! (Perhaps a first *puzzle* might be nice, but that part is up to you :P)

Comment: Fair enough, my first one wasn't a complete answer though. But either way, $\color{green}{\text{accepted}}$ or not, yay!

Comment: Yikes! I forgot to give you the tick on time! Sorry about that! Here you go :) $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ Congratulations! :D